# Untiy 2017.2.0f3: cant build android apk error: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to sign APK package

Tags: android, sdk, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build a test for my app. When i build the app i get the following error

```
 CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to sign APK package.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\apksigner.bat sign --ks "D:/Programming/UnityProjects/MobileProject-resortTycoon/user.keystore" --ks-pass stdin  --ks-key-alias "test123" --key-pass stdin  "D:\Programming\UnityProjects\MobileProject-resortTycoon\Temp/StagingArea/Package.apk"

 stderr[
 Error: keywords 'java|openjdk version' not found in 'picked up java_tool_options: -df'
 Error: keywords 'java|openjdk version' not found in 'picked up java_tool_options: -df'
 Failed to load signer "signer #1"
 java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
     at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:658)
     at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
     at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
     at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
     at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
     at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool$SignerParams.loadKeyStoreFromFile(ApkSignerTool.java:829)
     at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool$SignerParams.loadPrivateKeyAndCertsFromKeyStore(ApkSignerTool.java:719)
     at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool$SignerParams.loadPrivateKeyAndCerts(ApkSignerTool.java:659)
     at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool$SignerParams.access$500(ApkSignerTool.java:611)
     at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.sign(ApkSignerTool.java:266)
     at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.main(ApkSignerTool.java:89)
 Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
 ]
 stdout[
 Keystore password for signer #1: 
 ]
 exit code: 2
 UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
 UnityEditor.Android.Command.RunWithStdin (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg, System.String[] input)
 UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg, System.String[] stdin)
 UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildAPK.SignPackage (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
 UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildAPK.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
 UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
 UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

I already tried reinstalling the Android SDK and updating it to latest version, downloading a different android versions, using the new gradle instead of internal. Nothing worked. After 2 days of searching for a solution I still dont know how to fix this. Can someone help me? Thanks alot!

Comment: No one?! cant anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why but I was able to fix my problem. When I installed Java JDK, it installed 2 folders. Unity automatically selected 1 folder called "jdk-9". When I changed it to "jdk1.8.0_131" I was able to build my app.

If any knows why this works, I will be happy to know!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with your keystore and not the sdk. I don't know if you know what a keystore is, so here you go:

A keystore is a file that acts like a "password" for your app. Google play for example will not let you update your app unless the update is signed with the same keystore as your app. Whatever you do, do not lose the keystore after you publish your app.

If you have not jet generated a keystore for your app you can generate one in unity: https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-signing.62137/

If you already have a keystore it most likely got corrupted somehow. If you already published your app somewhere I hope you have a backup. If not just generate a new keystore

Comment: Thanks for your response. I made  a new keystore. and filled in everything. I tried to build the apk after this and it still gave me the error. Is it a problem if the keystore is not in the assets folder?